# TryValidateModel in asp.net core throws Null Reference Exception while performing unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I'm trying to write unit tests for ModelState validation for an Asp.Net Core Web API.

I read that, the best way to do so is to use `TryValidateModel` function. But, every time I run the unit test, it throws NullReference exception.
I found many articles suggesting `controller.ModelState.AddModelError("","")`, but I'm not interested in this, as I believe that it beats the actual purpose of the real model validation.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var controller = new TestController();

    controller.Post(new Model());
}


public class TestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Post(Model model)
    {
        bool b = TryValidateModel(model)

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

`TryValidateModel(model)` always throws NullReference Exception from `TryValidateModel(model, prefix)` function.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Shouldn't *controller.TestModel(new Model());* be *controller.Post(new Model());*

Comment: I don't know where you read the non-sense of `TryValidateModel` being best practice, but thats definitely not true. First, all the official tutorials used (or still use) `ModelState.IsValid`. Second, with ASP.NET Core 2.1 a new `[ApiController]` attribute has been added, which reduces the number of things one has to do in WebApi-esque controllers. Among them, is that models implicitly validated, so that `ModelState.IsValid` within the controller action isn't necessary and the validation action filter returns the appropriate "problem details" (also 2.1 feature)

Comment: Read [ASP.NET Core 2.1.0-preview1: Improvements for building Web APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-web-apis/) to learn more details about it

Comment: I updated the code to fix the wrong function call
. Thanks Marcus for the tip.

Comment: @Tseng This works fine with `ModelState.IsValid` when I deploy the application. The concern is when I unit test, `ModelState.IsValid` always returns `true`. It does not actually perform the model validations, which is where `TryValidateModel(model)` comes in, which is expected to forcefully validate. But, it is throwing Null Reference Exception for me.

Comment: Please read what i wrote :P validation happens during binding and this doesn't happen when you just pass the model. Use integration tests, for realistic model validation. unit tests are not suitable for that

Comment: Also keep in mind, if you ever switch to `[ApiController]`, all of your logic within the controller and your unit tests based on it become obsolete, since in real word the action will never be called if there is a model validation error when using attributed based model validation (either by creating your own action attribute that checks the validation or by using `ApiControllerAttribute`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's configuration/integration issue.

You can see some additional info in the [issue in ASP.NET Core repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3586) and [another one](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6000) on github.
But I can tell you the easiest fix (I used it once)

```
        var objectValidator = new Mock<IObjectModelValidator>();
        objectValidator.Setup(o => o.Validate(It.IsAny<ActionContext>(), 
                                          It.IsAny<ValidationStateDictionary>(), 
                                          It.IsAny<string>(), 
                                          It.IsAny<Object>()));
        controller.ObjectValidator = objectValidator.Object;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the OP is asking for, as it effectively always passes. If I get the op right he wants to test the validation itself

Comment: Yes, this is basically mocking the validation which will always be true. The OP wasn't asking for this, see his answer below.

Answer (score 4):

As I figured how to fix Null Reference Exception thanks to @Egorikas, I noticed that it still doesn't actually validate the model and always returns a true.

I found that we could just use `Validator` class in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`namespace.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var model = new Person();
    var validationResultList = new List<ValidationResult>();


    bool b1 = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, new ValidationContext(model), validationResultList);
}
```

You can directly validate it from the Test method itself, rather than having to call the controller, if ModelState validation is your intention.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It will still return true :(

Comment: @PresidentCamacho I got it to work for me for anything that would cause my API to return a 400. Could you give a little more information like what sort of properties are decorated with what sort of validation attributes?

Comment: One important note here, that the validation is not recursive, meaning only the top level is validated this way. Let's say there is a complex type Address in Person and you want to validate that this way, you need another line like:
`bool b2 = Validator.TryValidateObject(model.Address, new ValidationContext(model.Address), validationResultList);`

Comment: @Akos yes I noticed that :)

Comment: To have it validate all properties and attributes. Add a true as last parameter to TryValidateObjet. Like so: ```Validator.TryValidateObject(model, new ValidationContext(model), validationResultList, true);```

Answer (score 4):

Based on Andrew Van Den Brink answer's, but with actually having the validation errors set in the ModelState.

```
private class ObjectValidator : IObjectModelValidator
{

    public void Validate(ActionContext actionContext, ValidationStateDictionary validationState, string prefix, object model)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(model, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(
            model, context, results,
            validateAllProperties: true
        );

        if (!isValid)
            results.ForEach((r) =>
            {
                // Add validation errors to the ModelState
                actionContext.ModelState.AddModelError("", r.ErrorMessage);
            });
    }
}
```

Then, simply set the ObjectValidator in your controller:

```
controller.ObjectValidator = new ObjectValidator();
```

Comment: Works for me. Model that the controller tries to validate is actually validated using the validation logic in the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ObjectValidator : IObjectModelValidator
    {
        private object parameter;
        public ObjectValidator(object parameter)
        {
            this.parameter = parameter;
        }
        public void Validate(ActionContext actionContext, ValidationStateDictionary validationState, string prefix, object model)
        {                
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(parameter, null, null);
            System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.ValidateObject(model, validationContext);                
        }
    }

var model=new {}; // Model to test    
Controller controller = new Controller(); //Controller to test
controller.ObjectValidator = new ObjectValidator(model);
```

This one will throw exception